# How to populate the selected item in combobox when form control option having multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, combobox

I am trying to populate the saved selected item into the form control.

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option data-parameter-id="685" data-parent-id="1052" data-aggregation-id="null" data-aggregation-parameter="null">ABC</option>
    <option data-parameter-id="993" data-parent-id="0" data-aggregation-id="43" data-aggregation-parameter="2">DEF</option>
    <option data-parameter-id="993" data-parent-id="0" data-aggregation-id="39" data-aggregation-parameter="null">XYZ</option>
<select>
```

when i get the external input value(for ex: select 3rd row having data aggregation id=39) the corresponding value from the option has to be selected.
I have code written as

```
var savedOrderedAttributeId = $('#ordered-attribute-id').val();
var savedOrderedAttributeAggregationId = $('#ordered-aggregation-id').val();
var selectorForOptionWithSavedParameter = '"select"'+ ' option[data-aggregation-id="' + savedOrderedAttributeAggregationId + '"' + 'data-parameter-id="' + savedOrderedAttributeId + '"]';
$(controlSelector).find("select").val($(controlSelector).find(selectorForOptionWithSavedParameter).val());
```

what code change has to be done to select the option based on both the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to loop through your select options and check which option matches the data aggregation id you're looking for. E.g.

```js
var savedOrderedAttributeId = $('#ordered-attribute-id').val();
var savedOrderedAttributeAggregationId = $('#ordered-aggregation-id').val();
    
$('select option').each(function(o) {
  
  if($(this).data('aggregation-id') == savedOrderedAttributeAggregationId && 
     $(this).data('parameter-id') == savedOrderedAttributeId) {
    //alert('found it');
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
    <option data-parameter-id="685" data-parent-id="1052" data-aggregation-id="null" data-aggregation-parameter="null">ABC</option>
    <option data-parameter-id="993" data-parent-id="0" data-aggregation-id="43" data-aggregation-parameter="2">DEF</option>
    <option data-parameter-id="993" data-parent-id="0" data-aggregation-id="39" data-aggregation-parameter="null">XYZ</option>
<select>
```